# I can't register a service worker as i get the error: 'Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The URL protocol of the script is not supported.'

Tags: service-worker, tampermonkey

I am using TamperMonkey to create a userscript and am trying to create a service worker. I don't expect that the fact that its a userscript affects anything and don't think its CORS as I have been able to fetch the script from github. Here's the script:

```
==UserScript==
// @name                        New Userscript
// @namespace                   http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version                     0.1
// @description                 try to take over the world!
// @author                      You
// @match                       http://*/*
// @resource servicWorker.js    https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/basic/service-worker.js
// @grant                       GM_log
// @grant                       GM_getResourceURL
// ==/UserScript==


function getServiceURL(url) {
    const content = GM_getResourceURL(url);
    //return (`data:text/javascript;base64,${btoa(service_url)}`);
    return URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([content], {type: "text/javascript"}));
}

const service_url = "servicWorker.js"
const serviceScript = getServiceURL(service_url)

if (navigator && navigator.serviceWorker) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var service_Worker = navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceScript).then(
            (registration) => {
                GM_log(registration)
            },
            (error) => {
                GM_log(error)
            }
        )
    })
}
```

Here's the full error:

```
TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The URL protocol of the script ('blob:https://www.javascripttutorial.net/acb62aea-0338-4f99-a6f4-f2a3ddd984b8') is not supported.
```

I have checked the type of the 'serviceScript' which is the argument for 'navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceScript)' which is 'blob:[https://www.javascripttutorial.net/acb62ae...'](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/acb62ae...%27).
And using 'return (`data:text/javascript;base64,${btoa(service_url)}`);' the type is 'data:text/javascript;base64,c2Vydml...'

Comment: Service worker URL must belong to the site's domain, it can't be data: or blob:.

Comment: OK, thank you. So service workers can only be registered from HTTPS URLs (for security reasons I'm guessing) and I'll also assume that tampermonkey or chrome extensions can't bypass this however this would then mean extensions can't use service workers as extensions don't run on the same domains as the websites they extend. This is caused by CORS right.